# Unable to get the value of JSONObject in android

Tags: android, arrays, json

I am unable to get the value of the "wpcf-video" and "wpcf-icon" from the "custom_fields" Object from my JSON url. what I want is to get the value if each "wpcf" inside the custom fields and get it as a string so i can "putExtra" the value of it and getIntent it in the next activity. Please help.  Im beginner in android and it will be very helpful if i get much straight forward solution, Im doing this for my Thesis in my university. Thank you for understanding..

JSON URL:

```
    "status": "ok",
    "count": 3,
    "count_total": 3,
    "pages": 1,
    "posts": [
   {
  "id": 85,
  "title": "Lesson 3 commarts",
  "content": "<p>Lesson 3 commarts content here<\/p>\n",
  "excerpt": "<p>Lesson 3 commarts content here<\/p>\n",
  "custom_fields": {
    "wpcf-video": [
      ""
    ],
    "wpcf-pdf": [
      ""
    ],
    "wpcf-icon": [
      "http:\/\/loaapp.abundantlife.org.au\/wp-content\/uploads\/2014\/04\/icon2.png"
    ]
  }
},
{
  "id": 81,
  "title": "Lesson 2 Com Arts 1",
  "content": "<p>Lesson 2 Com Arts 1 Content Here<\/p>\n",
  "excerpt": "<p>Lesson 2 Com Arts 1 Content Here<\/p>\n",
  "custom_fields": {
    "wpcf-video": [
      ""
    ],
    "wpcf-pdf": [
      "http:\/\/loaapp.abundantlife.org.au\/wp-content\/uploads\/2014\/04\/single-course-layout.docx"
    ],
    "wpcf-icon": [
      "http:\/\/loaapp.abundantlife.org.au\/wp-content\/uploads\/2014\/04\/iconmenu.png"
    ]
  }
}
```

My Code:

```
    try {

                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost post = new HttpPost(params[0]);
                HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);

                int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

                if(status == 200){

                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    String data = EntityUtils.toString(entity);

                    JSONObject lessonObject = new JSONObject(data);
                    JSONArray lessonArray = lessonObject.getJSONArray("posts");

                    for (int i = 0; i < lessonArray.length(); i++){

                        JSONObject objectLesson = lessonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                        LessonArrayTemplate LessonTemplateArrayList = new LessonArrayTemplate();

                        LessonTemplateArrayList.setTitle(objectLesson.getString("title"));
                        LessonTemplateArrayList.setExcerpt(objectLesson.getString("excerpt").replaceAll("<(.*?)\\>","").replaceFirst("(.*?)\\>", "").replaceAll("&rarr;","").replace("Continue reading", ""));
                        LessonTemplateArrayList.setId(objectLesson.getString("id"));

                        JSONObject customFieldsObject = objectLesson.getJSONObject("custom_fields");

                        //fetching the url of the video
                        LessonTemplateArrayList.setVideo(customFieldsObject.getString("wpcf-video").replace("\\", ""));
                        LessonTemplateArrayList.setIconImage(customFieldsObject.getString("wpcf-icon").replace("\\", ""));


                        // sample input but this should be the image 

                        comArtsArrayList.add(LessonTemplateArrayList);  
                    }
```

Comment: what error you got post full logcat

Comment: actually there is no error in it.. i just didnt get the value of the "wpcf-video" and "wpcf-icon".. I want the value of those so i can use it in another activity to show in list view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this way

Replace these two lines

```
LessonTemplateArrayList.setVideo(customFieldsObject.getString("wpcf-video").replace("\\", ""));
LessonTemplateArrayList.setIconImage(customFieldsObject.getString("wpcf-icon").replace("\\", ""));
```

With

```
LessonTemplateArrayList.setVideo(customFieldsObject.getJSONArray("wpcf-video").getString(0));
    LessonTemplateArrayList.setIconImage(customFieldsObject.getJSONArray("wpcf-icon").getString(0));
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
           try {

                    HttpClient httpclient2 = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpPost httppost2 = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2:80/contactcheck.php");

                    HttpResponse response2 = httpclient2.execute(httppost2); 
                    HttpEntity entity2 = response2.getEntity();
                    is2 = entity2.getContent();

                    Log.e("log_tag", "connection success ");

            }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());


                }

                try
                {
                        BufferedReader reader2 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
                        StringBuilder sb2 = new StringBuilder();
                        String line = null;
                        while ((line = reader2.readLine()) != null) 
                        {
                                sb2.append(line + "\n");

                        }
                        is.close();

                        result2=sb2.toString();
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                       Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());


                }
                try
                {
                    JSONArray jArray2 = new JSONArray(result3);
                    String s11;
                    Log.w("Lengh",""+jArray2.length());
                      for(int i=0;i<jArray2.length();i++){


                        JSONObject json_data2 = jArray2.getJSONObject(i);

                           s11=json_data2.getString("phno");





                      }  
                }

                catch(JSONException e)
                {
                        Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());

                }
```

Comment: sorry I dont get what this is.. all i can see that it is parsing from one arraylist, but not in the 2nd one which what I want to get. please have a look in the JSON URL i got.

Comment: try this code. rename with your url. you can get json array object in   JSONObject json_data2 = jArray2.getJSONObject(i);

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  JSONArray videoArray =  customFieldsObject.getJSONArray("wpcf-video")  ;
  JSONArray iconArray =  customFieldsObject.getJSONArray("wpcf-icon");
  if(videoArray.length()>0){
             LessonTemplateArrayList.setVideo(videoArray.get(0));
}
  if(iconArray.length()>0){
            LessonTemplateArrayList.setIconImage(iconArray.get(0));
}
```

instead of

```
  customFieldsObject.getString("wpcf-video").replace("\\", "");
  customFieldsObject.getString("wpcf-icon").replace("\\", "");
```

`wpcf-video` and `wpcf-icon` are jsonArray, so get them as JSONArray

Comment: Got an error with it "The method setVideo(String) in the type LessonArrayTemplate is not applicable for the arguments (JSONArray)"..
what i did is this ...LessonTemplateArrayList.setVideo(customFieldsObject.getJSONArray("wpcf-video");

Comment: you need to pars those array again to get the respective string.